# Is there a way to cut a sprite sheet into individual images in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, sprite-sheet

I am working with a sprite sheet, and I want to generate individual images for each frame, hopefully using some convenient naming convention.

I've set the image grid so that each individual frame is in a rectangle of the grid, and I was hoping that GIMP could automatically generate a list of files using this spacing and offset, naming the images after the row and column they're in. If I had the file list, however, it would be trivial to have them named properly using a simple script, therefore the naming of the files would just be a convenient addition.

I'm currently manually cutting each frame using the crop tool, then exporting it as a PNG, reloading the sheet file and repeating. Since I'll be doing this with a large number of sprites, each with a far more frames than I'm currently working with, this method will soon become unsustainable.

Comment: Questions about generally using software (rather than programming) may be better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com). That said, Google suggests Gimp's [Guillotine](https://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-guillotine.html) command. If the images are all the same size, you can also write a shell script for it with `pnmcut` from Netpbm or `convert` from ImageMagick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "py-slice" plug-in that ships with GIMP have a similar functionality, although it relies on image guides - 
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/blob/master/plug-ins/pygimp/plug-ins/py-slice.py

It should be relatively easy to change that script to work with fixed-sized rectangles and internal padding instead of creating its rectangles from manual positioned guides.

In special you won't need almost any of the code in the `for` loops that interact on horizontal and vertical guides, on lines 90-127 , there, and also, none of the HTML generating stuff -

Instead, add the "sprite width, height, internal paddings" as inputs, and iterate the rectangles - and change some parameters in the "register" call so that your file register itself as another plug-in, instead of the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

The [ofn-tiles script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/) will do this, but it doesn't take spacing in account.

To remove spacing you can use the `unshred` function of the [ofn-shred-layer script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/), once vertically and once horizontally (note: you give it the width of the strips, not of the tiles).